# Python, Django: Merge respectively join multiple models with foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Good evening,

I would like to ask if there's a possibility inside django (database-queries) to merge multiple models with one request. I'm not very good in sql but I think it's called *join* or *merge* there?

**models.py**

```
class ObjectA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class ObjectB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    object_a = models.ForeignKey(ObjectA, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ObjectC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    object_b = models.ForeignKey(ObjectB, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**What I'm trying to achive...**

```
object_a  |  object_b_name  |  object_b_amount  |  object_c_name  |  object_c_amount
a_01      |    b_01         |    17             |    c_01         |    42
a_01      |    b_02         |    21             |    c_02         |    0
a_02      |    b_03         |    145            |    c_02         |    29
a_03      |    b_04         |    0              |    c_02         |    31
a_03      |    b_05         |    0              |    c_04         |    102
a_04      |    b_06         |    73             |    c_09         |    54
```

Is something like this possible or is it a problem, that each class only contains the foreignkey to the "previous level"?

Hoping someone has an answer!? Thanks to all of you and have a great weekend!

Comment: Have you tried using [`select_related(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)?

Comment: Thanks you very much! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bee I found the solution! It's called *select_related*.

```
ObjectC.objects.select_related('object_b').select_related('object_b__object_a')
```